# JavaScript Array's/methods and Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

```
export function getPlanetNames(data) {
  const pNames = data.planets;
  const results = pNames.filter(function (getNames) {
    return getNames.name;
  });
  return results;
```

'data' is in another file with an object array with attributes.

data = { planets: [{blah blah blah}] asteroids: [{blah blah blah blah}]}

why is my code above not pulling the planets array.name which is the attribute of the planets array.

Comment: "*'data' is in another file*" - no, `data` in your function refers to the parameter, so it is whatever the caller of the `getPlanetNames` passes in as the argument. Whether some other files declares `data` or not does not matter.

Comment: I see what you are getting at, however this exercise is referring to a specific file of a data object of arrays with attributes in them. So when I am creating this function the test file that sees if my function runs properly tells me if I am doing it right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually filter function in Js doesn't returns specific key of object to assigned array. It is for filtering the elements of array based on conditions given. Try **Map** method.

```
    export function getPlanetNames(data) {
       const pNames = data.planets;
       const results = pNames.map(function (getNames) {
       return getNames.name;
     });
     return results;}
```

Now the results variable will have array of planet names.

Comment: That did it actually. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
export function getPlanetNames(data) {
  const pNames = data.planets;
  const results = pNames.map(function (getNames) {
    return getNames.name;
  });
  return results;
}
```

This worked for me

Comment: It's a copy of another answer to the same question.